# Prove that $2^{66}-1$ is not a prime number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, prime-numbers

I just started studying Discrete Mathematics and one of the exercises asks to prove that:

$$2^{66} - 1 \textrm{ is not a prime number}$$

The author suggests to use the well know relation:

$$x^2 - 1 = (x + 1)(x - 1)$$

My proof goes as such (please forgive me — and do correct me — if I use any wrong symbol or term). Let's define the set $X$ as:

$$X=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\;|\;n>2\}$$

$\forall x\in X$ we define two numbers:

$$\begin{align}a & = x+1\\ b & = x-1\end{align}$$

Because $x>2$, then $a>1$ and $b>1$. Therefore we have

$$c=a\cdot b$$

which cannot be a prime number, because:

$$\frac{c}{a}=b \quad \textrm{or} \quad \frac{c}{b}={a}$$

This, in my view, is the proof of the theorem.

Could you please let me know if my proof is correct, or if not, how do I prove the theorem?

Thank you very much!

Valerio

Edit: As cited in the comments/answers below, I didn't show the factorisation, so here we go:

$$2^{66}-1=(2^{33}+1)(2^{33}-1)$$

Now I understand I didn't need to use all the steps above, but I was trying to give a general proof, not just for the specific case.

Anyway, thank you all for your answers and showing interest in my question. I didn't expect it to create so much debate! :-)

Comment: In your proof, you haven't declared what $x$ is. So it does not addresses the result you want to prove.

Comment: your number is divisible by $3$

Comment: I suggest you call $x=2^{33}$

Comment: You have indeed proven that if $x$ is an integer greater than $2$ then $x^2 -1$ is not prime.  But you haven't in any way stated what that has to do with $2^{66} -1$ being prime or not.  BTW, there was no reason to introduce the variables $a,b,$ or $c$.  It'd have been enough (and a *LOT* easier to read) if you just said.  $x^2 -1 = (x+1)(x-1)$ and as $x+1$ and $x-1$ are integers that are not equal to $1$, $x^2 -1$ is  not prime.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

Just a little tip - for a problem like this, you don't need to have such a complex proof. It should just suffice to show that
$$2^{66}-1=(2^{33}+1)(2^{33}-1)$$
and then show that
$$2^{33}+1 \ne 1 \ne 2^{33}-1$$
$$2^{33}+1 \ne 2^{66}-1 \ne 2^{33}-1$$
Which should be fairly simple.

But your proof seems fine to me!

Edit: There's one thing that you missed, as @AndrewD.Hwang pointed out in the comments - you have not actually shown that $2^{66}-1$ can be factored in the way that you decided to use.

But that's okay, it's a quick fix!

Comment: Aww, why the down vote? Whoever it was, please let me know how I can improve my post. :(

Comment: I didn't downvote, but what the OP currently has written is not a complete proof: If $2^{66}$ were replaced by $2^{3}$, say, the "argument" would "prove" that $2^{3} - 1 = 7$ is not prime, contrary to fact,

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Umm... no, it would not. $2^3-1$ cannot be expressed in the form $(x+1)(x-1)$ where $x$ is a member of the set $X$ described by the OP.

Comment: That's the point: OP hasn't shown that $2^{66}-1$ _can_ be factored as stated. (To see that this has not been shown, replace the exponent $66$ by $3$ and try to point to the incorrect step.)

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. Okay, thanks! I'll add that to my answer. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, I don't see where this answer's proof was incorrect.  Or did you mean just the OP's proof?

Comment: @Wildcard He didn't say it was incorrect, just "lacking in thorough-ness". :P

Comment: @Wildcard: What I meant was, the OP's original proof was incomplete, and therefore the original draft of this answer might have attracted a downvote by claiming the OP's original proof was correct. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Beware: overkill. I hope an *interesting* overkill.
 Let $\omega(n)$ be the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ and $\nu_3(n)=\max\{m\in\mathbb{N}: 3^m\mid n\}$.

---

$$2^{66}-1 = (2^{33}-1)(2^{33}+1),\qquad \gcd(2^{33}+1,2^{33}-1)=\gcd(2^{33}+1,2)=1 $$
hence $\omega(2^{66}-1) = \omega(2^{33}-1)+\omega(2^{33}+1)$. Additionally
$$ 2^{33}-1 = (2^{11}-1)(2^{22}+2^{11}+1),$$ 
$$ \gcd(2^{22}+2^{11}+1,2^{11}-1)=\gcd(3,2^{11}-1)=1 $$
from which $\omega(2^{33}-1)\geq 2$. In a similar way
$$ 2^{33}+1 = (2^{11}+1)(2^{22}-2^{11}+1),$$
$$ \gcd(2^{22}-2^{11}+1,2^{11}+1)=3$$
and since $\nu_3(2^{33}+1)=2$ we also have $\omega(2^{33}+1)\geq 3$ and 
$$\boxed{ 2^{66}-1\text{ has at least }\color{red}{5}\text{ distinct prime factors}.} $$

---

Actually $2^{66}-1$ has $8$ distinct prime factors, and the smallest of them, $\{3,7,23, 67,89\}$, are not difficult to recognize. $2,6,22,66$ are divisors of $66$, so $\{3,7,23,67\}$ are prime divisors of $2^{66}-1$ by Fermat's little theorem. $89$ is a divisor since $89\mid(2^{11}-1)\mid(2^{66}-1)$.

Comment: Way, way, way overkill.  But, yes, interesting and potentially (down the line) useful overkill.  But as is ...way.... overkill.  +1 for being honest.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is correct but I have three critiques.

1) You never actually answer the question whether $2^{66} -1$ is prime or not.

Somewhere you need to state that if $n = 2^{33}$ than $2^{66}-1 = n^2 -1$ which isn't prime.  Yes, it's obvious.  But you never actually indicated *how* what you were proving applies to the question at hand.

(I know... it was obvious and was abundantly clear to you.... but nonetheless, it should be stated.)

2) Adding the variables $a,b,c$ simply obfuscates.

It's more direct to simply say $n^2 - 1 = (n+1)(n-1)$.   So if $n+1$ and $n-1$ are natural number other than $1$ (i.e. $n > 2$) then $(n+1)(n-1) = n^2 -1$ is composite and not prime.

3) You don't actually have to *state* or prove that $x^2 - 1$ is not prime for $x > 2$.  It's enough to *use* it as a hint.

The proof can be done in one sentence:

$2^{66} = (2^{33} + 1)(2^{33} -1)$ so $2^{66} -1$ has factors other than itself and $1$ so it is not prime.  QED.

Comment: Thank you for the critique @fleablood. I see why my proof is convulted, though correct. I’m satisfied that I solved the problem and I’ll learn to be more concise.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised that there hasn't been a single mention of the term "Mersenne prime" or at least "Mersenne number" in the answers so far. I admit that aside from that detail, the answer I'm going to give is hardly different from the others.

It is a well-known fact that if $2^n - 1$ is prime (a Mersenne prime), then $n$ must itself be prime. And it is also well known that if $n$ is prime, then $2^n - 1$ is not necessarily prime.

In fact, it's much more likely to be composite. $2^{74207281} - 1$ is *believed* to be the $49$th Mersenne prime, and $74207281$ is itself the $4350601$st prime overall. Suppose they find a hundred Mersenne prime exponents between $37156667$ and $74207281$. That's unlikely, but it would still mean that less than $1\%$ of primes up to $74207281$ are Mersenne prime exponents.

The fact that composite $n$ means $2^n - 1$ is also composite has been known since before Marin Mersenne's time. To use the hint that was given to you, note that $$2^{2m} = (2^m)^2.$$ Since $66 = 2 \times 33$, it follows that $$2^{66} - 1 = (2^{33} - 1)(2^{33} + 1).$$ Clearly $1 < 2^{33} - 1 < 2^{33} + 1 < 2^{66} - 1$, meaning that $2^{66} - 1$ is divisible by positive integers other than $1$ and itself.

Comment: *also raises hand* @Typhon That's right, there's only one Mersenne prime with an *even* exponent: $2^2 - 1 = 1 \times 3 = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Start with let $2^{66}-1$, Then factor it as follows:
$$2^{66}-1=(2^{33})^2-1=(2^{33}+1)(2^{33}-1).$$
Now proceed from here.